# Is it possible to run JBPM5 in standalone mode

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management

I was able to run the JBPM4 in a standalone mode in the past (No application server or external dependencies).

However JBPM 5.4 seems difficult to do so.
It has Drools, Human Task service dependencies and some other dependencies that will require a separate setup.

***Has any one EVER run jbpm 5.4 in a standalone mode?***

Which means having a database setup with the required tables and JBPM will run as a plain old java program.

JBPM5 claims it's embeddable, but there are no clear guidelines on how to create jbpm embeddable; say in a Websphere application server, with an oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is done very often, and all our junit tests and pure Java examples work like this.  Even the database is optional, the core engine is a POJO, possibly working together with other POJOs (like task service) or possibly deployed on an application server, but that is no requirement.

If you look at the hello world examples or JUnit test examples in Eclipse for example, they are almost all running as a simple POJO.

Deploying jBPM on WAS is a supported product configuration even.

Kris

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how could the test run with out a database? Creating Knowledge builder and knowledge base will require a database to be there to put the content in, isn't it?